# Matlab system() running C++ Executable

Tags: c++, matlab, system, executable

I'm having some trouble getting Matlab to run an executable file. Essentially, I have a C++ code that does some calculations and outputs these calculations to a text file; then, Matlab reads these text files and uses the calculations to makes plots and stuff.

I've been trying to get Matlab to run the C++ exe file so that, when it runs it, the output files are automatically generated and Matlab can start doing its stuff. This just allows the user to run the program quicker. I am using the system() command Like so:

```
    system('MyCppProgram.exe');
```

However, when I run that, although everything compiles, nothing is outputted from CPP and I even get back something that says "ans = -1" and I have no idea what that means.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Update:  Result from test command.

```
[status, cmdout] = system('MyCppProgram.exe', '-echo');

status = -1

cmdout = ''
```

Comment: Not in the path, some shared library not in path?

Comment: I'm sure its in the same path, and for a couple of reasons. First of all, the cpp.exe file and all the matlab files are in the same path, and when I manually run the .exe file, Matlab reads the outputs just fine (I dont need to specify the path in the matlab code either). Moreover, Matlab explicitly tells me its in the same path as the .exe file. Last but not least.. even if I specify the path, it doesnt work.

Comment: Ok, @Matt cmdout is empty (0x0char value: ") and status = -1.

Comment: Alright, that is not one I've seen before.  Add the `&` after your executable such as `[status, cmdout] = system('MyCppProgram.exe &', '-echo');`.  This should open the shell so you can see what's happening.  Also what operating system are you running?  Are you administrator?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will make a difference, but have you tried using shell escape?  You do this : `!MyCppProgram.exe&`

Comment: What happens if you execute the CPP program from that directory outside of Matlab? The problem may be with your MyCppProgram.exe if it indeed is returning an exit code of -1 (generally signifies error) and no output. I'd edit the CPP program to printf("hello world"); right when it starts so you can tell if it is indeed being run.